# What range scale does a human-sized Mek-Pirate use?

Tags: 3d-space, hacking, mekton

Some of the really nice tech in the Mekton Workshop costs a lot. Cloaking demands to add 0.8 to the final cost multiplier for active, fire control, combat cloaking.<sup>1</sup> And another 0.33 for a the *dirty trick* Piracy Module.<sup>2</sup> Those result in a total multiplier of \$1+0.8+0.33=2.13\$ before we add any other tech and with the normal guns and equipment that makes that combo really hard to pay for. As in, you go over budget really fast.

However, we can always scale down to cut costs. Going human scale cuts it to 1/5th of the cost.<sup>3</sup> The result might be best described as a [MechWarrior-Clan-Elemental](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/Elemental) sized armor with [Predator cloaking](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Cloak) that also houses a Hollywood hacker.

So, a human-sized, near-invisible, Mek-pirating body armor for \$2.13\times \frac 1 5 =0.43\$ of the price of all the other gear stuffed into it? Sounds like a steal. Sure, this armor takes no hits from a proper Mek, but... wait, there's a problem: Do you need to pretty much climb upon the enemy or is the human-sized hacker the bane of any pilot within some Mek-Hexes?

> [Reference to the chart on p.53] The control range and operation range are both considered to be equal to the pirating mecha pilot's Piloting skill <sup>4</sup>.

Now, the whole game is usually scaled in Hexes for Meks on one hand, and in meters for pilots on the other. When scaling a *weapon* down, the rules explicitly tell what to do with weapon range and damage. But nothing I can see points to scaling *dirty tricks*. The Piracy Module is such a dirty trick. Does that mean we use the Hex ranges from page 53? Or convert them somehow into meters, possibly using the Electronic Warfare range conversion formula on page 108?

**What range scale is used for our tiny hacker's piracy ability? Mek-hexes (50-meter steps) or the handgun-meter-scale?**

---

1. <sub>Mekton Zeta Plus - Advanced Technical Manual p.75</sub>
2. <sub>Mekton Zeta Plus - Advanced Technical Manual p.93</sub>
3. <sub>Mekton Zeta Plus - Advanced Technical Manual p.107</sub>
4. <sub>Mekton Zeta Plus - Advanced Technical Manual p.93</sub>